# Form validate PreventDefault works only locally but not on the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, preventdefault

I try to submit a form with ajax, and with the jquery validate() function. When I test it locally, the event.preventDefault() works! Also without the line "event.preventDefault();" but, when I deploy it to the server, the result json loads in a new page - it doesen't prevent the redirect.

```
$(function () {
    $("#photo-form").validate({
        submitHandler: function (form, event) {
            event.preventDefault(); //with or without - doesn't work
            if ($(form)[0].checkValidity()) {
                console.log("No Errors!")
                var formData = new FormData(document.querySelector("#photo-form"));
                var photo = formData.get("photo");

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/photo/",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: formData,
                    async: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log("Ajax success");
                        if (data.error == "OK") {
                              alert("Photo was uploaded");
                        } else {
                              //error
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false
                });
                return false; //this also doesn't help 
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Where is the error in this case? What is the difference between local and server for this code?

HTML form:

```
<form id="photo-form" action="/photo/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
          class="row col s10 center-block">
        <div class="card row">
            <div class="col s12">
                <h5>Generic Information</h5>
                <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
                    <i class="material-icons prefix">title</i>
                    <input id="campaign_id" type="text" name="campaign_id" class="validate" required>
                    <label for="campaign_id" data-error="huh?" data-success="WOW!">campaign_id</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
                    <div class="file-field input-field">
                        <button class="btn btn-floating pink lighten-1 file-btn">
                            <span>Photo</span>
                            <input name="photo" type="file">
                        </button>
                        <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                            <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s8">
                        <button class="btn-large waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">Submit
                            <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
```

Comment: Open your browser console and check for errors.

Comment: Check for any Javascript error in the console.

Comment: Show us the HTML markup for the form... how are your rules declared?

Comment: Console Logs: 
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json: "myApp.herokuapp.com/photo/";. Navigated to myApp.herokuapp.com/photo content_script.js:84 Bind hotkeys

Answer (score 1):

It might be since your are trying to load jquery libs with HTTP while your session is with HTTPS. Make sure you are loading jquery with https://

Answer (score 0):

> Form validate PreventDefault works only locally but not on the server

Technically, it does not matter where the code is hosted, `.preventDefault()` is JavaScript and always/only works locally (client-side) in the browser.  So your problem is elsewhere... i.e. broken JavaScript after uploading to server.

---

Despite your testing, you have some mistakes within your code:

1. `submitHandler: function(form, event) { ...`

   You cannot invent arguments to pass into a callback provided by the plugin's developer.  He simply gives you the `form` argument, and that is all.  The `event` argument is meaningless here and will be ignored.
2. `event.preventDefault()` **will be** ignored.  See item #1; the `event` argument has no meaning in this context.
3. You do not need `event.preventDefault()` in the first place.  The plugin automatically handles capturing the click and blocking the default `submit` action, internally.
4. `if ($(form)[0].checkValidity()) { ...`

   Presumably you're checking to see if the form passes validation before allowing your `ajax` submission.  This too is completely unnessary.  By definition, the `submitHandler` [only fires when the form is already valid](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler).

   Also, `checkValidity()` is tied into HTML5 validation, which is totally disabled by the jQuery Validate plugin when it's initialized.  At best, this would do nothing, however, you should remove it.

   (It's a moot point, but you also would not need the `[0]` since the `$(form)` selector is using the `form` argument as provided by the plugin.)

---

*In your local testing you have nothing breaking the plugin or preventing it from operating normally.  Since the plugin already prevents the default submit automatically, you falsely believe that your `.preventDefault()` is doing something.  After deployment, you falsely believe that your `.preventDefault()` suddenly stops working, when instead the entire plugin is broken likely due to some reason bulleted below.*

---

If the plugin is not blocking your default form submit action, then likely you have one or more of these conditions:

- jQuery and/or jQuery Validate plugin not properly included
- Error(s) blocking execution of your JavaScript
- Improper declaration of validation rules causing form to appear valid
- HTML markup issue(s) (bad selector(s), etc.) preventing initialization of the plugin on your form element
- Invalid HTML, such as duplicate `id`, etc.
- Some other issue preventing proper initialization of the plugin

---

**Working**:

```
$(function () {
    $("#photo-form").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            console.log("No Errors!");
            console.log("form data: " + $(form).serialize());
            $.ajax({
                ....
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

**DEMO**:  [jsfiddle.net/b9x4626a/](http://jsfiddle.net/b9x4626a/)

Comment: Fixed the errors. Have still the same problems. Locally it works, on deployment it doesn't. My form is on photo/new and it redirects to /photo Here is the console log: 
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json: "https://myApp.herokuapp.com/photo/".
Navigated to https://myApp.herokuapp.com/photo/
content_script.js:84 Bind hotkeys

Comment: @PomeGranate, I have no idea about what you have at `content_script.js:84`... however, this has nothing to do with the jQuery Validate plugin or `.preventDefault()`.  You'll need to fix those JavaScript errors, otherwise, the remaining JavaScript on the page will not work.

Comment: @PomeGranate, in other words, your form is submitting because upon deployment, your JavaScript is totally broken... it has nothing to do with the original premise of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Check the javascript files include into the View. If you was using the Bundle to manage css & js libraries, you may try to include that by normal way with script, link tag.

In the past, I have same problem with you after deploy my app to the webserver.
Hope this help.

Comment: thank you for your advice, I use grunt for uglify and so on, maybe it has something to do with that? hmm